# Automate backing up e-mails in Outlook Express

Tags: backup, automation, export, outlook-express

My client is a small business (three employees) that uses Outlook Express. They'd like to back up their email. I showed them how to export, but they balked at that. Is there a way I can automate exporting email? They already have a batch file they use that zips a copy of their data and I'd like to be able to add something to that to include email. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to back up and to restore Outlook Express data](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/270670)

Someone how I missed this when Googling (not sure how, it's the first result). Anyway, in short, OE stores mail messages in a specified folder. I was able to accomplish what I wanted by including that folder's contents in the backup batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Mailstore Home](http://www.mailstore.com/en/mailstore-home.aspx)? This will allow them to backup their emails on Outlook Express without much trouble. The software is free.

Comment: I like this, but these folks didn't want to have to do anything they're not already doing. They're already double-clicking an icon on their desktop (shortcut to a batch file) every Friday that does all their backups. They wanted mail included in that.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that this approach of backing up the mail will NOT work if you're using IMAP. If the email is deleted from the IMAP server, you will lose the mail and your backup files will also become useless, as when restored, OE will quickly delete the messages from the local folders which have been removed from the server. Only use this method to backup if you're using the older POP3 protocol.